Pip NewConnectionError while creating conda environment from YAML file
Pip fails to install packages and has a "NewConnectionError". It fails on the first pip package, aiohttp. I am running these commands in ubuntu on a windows PC. Below is the error message that I get.
Channels:
 - defaults
 - conda-forge
Platform: linux-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

Downloading and Extracting Packages:

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Installing pip dependencies: | Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/home/henrydavis88/anaconda3/envs/automoldesigner/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/home/henrydavis88/test/AutoMolDesigner/condaenv.fajfa6ib.requirements.txt', '--exists-action=b']
Pip subprocess output:

Pip subprocess error:
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa3c7c6d6a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/aiohttp/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa3c7c6d9a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/aiohttp/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa3c7c6dc10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/aiohttp/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa3c7c6ddc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/aiohttp/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa3c7c6dfa0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known')': /simple/aiohttp/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement aiohttp==3.8.5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiohttp==3.8.5

failed

CondaEnvException: Pip failed

Here is the YAML file, it is named environment.yml
name: automoldesigner
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - _openmp_mutex=5.1=1_gnu
  - ca-certificates=2023.05.30=h06a4308_0
  - ld_impl_linux-64=2.38=h1181459_1
  - libffi=3.4.4=h6a678d5_0
  - libgcc-ng=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libgomp=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - libstdcxx-ng=11.2.0=h1234567_1
  - ncurses=6.4=h6a678d5_0
  - openssl=3.0.10=h7f8727e_0
  - pip=23.2.1=py39h06a4308_0
  - python=3.9.16=h955ad1f_3
  - readline=8.2=h5eee18b_0
  - setuptools=68.0.0=py39h06a4308_0
  - sqlite=3.41.2=h5eee18b_0
  - tk=8.6.12=h1ccaba5_0
  - tzdata=2023c=h04d1e81_0
  - wheel=0.38.4=py39h06a4308_0
  - xz=5.4.2=h5eee18b_0
  - zlib=1.2.13=h5eee18b_0
  - pip:
    - aiohttp==3.8.5
    - aiohttp-cors==0.7.0
    - aiosignal==1.3.1
    - async-timeout==4.0.3
    - attrs==23.1.0
    - autogluon-common==0.8.2
    - autogluon-core==0.8.2
    - autogluon-features==0.8.2
    - autogluon-tabular==0.8.2
    - blessed==1.20.0
    - blis==0.7.10
    - boto3==1.28.30
    - botocore==1.31.30
    - cachetools==5.3.1
    - catalogue==2.0.9
    - catboost==1.2
    - certifi==2023.7.22
    - charset-normalizer==3.2.0
    - click==8.1.7
    - cloudpickle==2.2.1
    - colorful==0.5.5
    - confection==0.1.1
    - contourpy==1.1.0
    - cycler==0.11.0
    - cymem==2.0.7
    - descriptastorus==2.6.1
    - dimorphite-dl==1.3.2
    - distlib==0.3.7
    - fastai==2.7.12
    - fastcore==1.5.29
    - fastdownload==0.0.7
    - fastprogress==1.0.3
    - filelock==3.12.2
    - fonttools==4.42.1
    - frozenlist==1.4.0
    - future==0.18.3
    - google-api-core==2.11.1
    - google-auth==2.22.0
    - googleapis-common-protos==1.60.0
    - gpustat==1.1
    - grpcio==1.50.0
    - hyperopt==0.2.7
    - idna==3.4
    - importlib-resources==6.0.1
    - jinja2==3.1.2
    - jmespath==1.0.1
    - joblib==1.3.2
    - jsonschema==4.19.0
    - jsonschema-specifications==2023.7.1
    - kiwisolver==1.4.4
    - langcodes==3.3.0
    - lightgbm==3.3.5
    - markupsafe==2.1.3
    - matplotlib==3.7.2
    - molvs==0.1.1
    - msgpack==1.0.5
    - multidict==6.0.4
    - murmurhash==1.0.9
    - networkx==3.1
    - numpy==1.25.2
    - nvidia-cublas-cu11==11.10.3.66
    - nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11==11.7.99
    - nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.7.99
    - nvidia-cudnn-cu11==8.5.0.96
    - nvidia-ml-py==12.535.77
    - opencensus==0.11.2
    - opencensus-context==0.1.3
    - packaging==23.1
    - pandas==1.5.3
    - pandas-flavor==0.6.0
    - pathy==0.10.2
    - pillow==10.0.0
    - platformdirs==3.10.0
    - plotly==5.16.1
    - preshed==3.0.8
    - prometheus-client==0.17.1
    - protobuf==4.24.1
    - psutil==5.9.5
    - py-spy==0.3.14
    - py4j==0.10.9.7
    - pyasn1==0.5.0
    - pyasn1-modules==0.3.0
    - pydantic==1.10.12
    - pyparsing==3.0.9
    - pyside6==6.5.2
    - pyside6-addons==6.5.2
    - pyside6-essentials==6.5.2
    - python-dateutil==2.8.2
    - python-graphviz==0.20.1
    - pytz==2023.3
    - pyyaml==6.0.1
    - ray==2.3.1
    - rdkit==2023.3.3
    - referencing==0.30.2
    - requests==2.31.0
    - rpds-py==0.9.2
    - rsa==4.9
    - s3transfer==0.6.2
    - scikit-learn==1.2.2
    - scipy==1.11.2
    - shiboken6==6.5.2
    - six==1.16.0
    - smart-open==6.3.0
    - spacy==3.6.1
    - spacy-legacy==3.0.12
    - spacy-loggers==1.0.4
    - srsly==2.4.7
    - tabulate==0.9.0
    - tenacity==8.2.3
    - tensorboardx==2.6.2.2
    - thinc==8.1.12
    - threadpoolctl==3.2.0
    - torch==1.13.1
    - torchvision==0.14.1
    - tqdm==4.66.1
    - typer==0.9.0
    - typing-extensions==4.7.1
    - urllib3==1.26.16
    - virtualenv==20.24.3
    - wasabi==1.1.2
    - wcwidth==0.2.6
    - xarray==2023.8.0
    - xgboost==1.7.6
    - yarl==1.9.2
    - zipp==3.16.2

I tried removing the aiohttp package but then I ran into the same failure with the aiohttp-cors package. I am still new to this type of programming so it is likely I missed something obvious.

You real error is ERROR: No matching distribution found for aiohttp==3.8.5. I don't know about aiohttp, but apparently they follow Python's versions. Which Python is in your env? 3.8.5?

You can check that it exists here = https://pypi.org/project/aiohttp/3.8.5/ so it's probably not suitable to your python's version

@AlexanderSantos The real error is "Name or service not known". DNS or network problem.

Oh it's true, didn't notice it. Do you have access to the machine @henrydavis88? You can try installing it manually and checking if the error persists. The registry is probably not reachable (as aiohttp is the first package from pip's registry, it will throw this error, probably it would throw it for any packages in pip)
